Error creating set: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce') when sending a POST request
I am following this tutorial but I am stuck at minute 30-ish where I should be able to send a POST request.
Details about the tutorial :

using React Native for a flashcard application
Xata as the backend provider

Here are the code snippets for the POST request:
app.post('/sets', async (req, res) => {
  const { title, description, private: isPrivate, creator, image } = req.body;

  // Validate input values
  if (!title || !description || isPrivate === undefined || !creator) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Missing required fields' });
  }

  try {
      const set = await client.db.sets.create({
          title,
          description,
          private: isPrivate,
          creator,
          image,
      });

      console.log('set: ', set);
      return res.json(set);
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating set:', error);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while creating the set' });
  }
});

There are two sorts of output when I send the request through insomnia:
First case being this in JSON:
{
    "title": "Chapter 1",
    "description": "This is a description of Chapter 1.",
    "private": false,
    "creator": "user123",
    "image": "http://example.com/image.jpg"
}

I received the error:
{
    "error": "An error occurred while creating the set"
}

in insomnia
but when I send this as JSON:
{
    "title" : "Learn about Dina",
   "description" : "no idea",
   "private": true,
   "creator" :null,
    "image":null
}

I received:
{
    "error": "Missing required fields"
}

sSo which one is closer to fixing? I am stuck at this for days and I have zero clue and the terminal log being this is not helpful too:
Error creating set: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')
    at promiseMap (C:\Users\addin\flashcards-react\api\node_modules\@xata.io\client\src\util\lang.ts:139:22)
    at RestRepository.transformObjectToApi_fn (C:\Users\addin\flashcards-react\api\node_modules\@xata.io\client\src\schema\repository.ts:2023:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async RestRepository.insertRecordWithoutId_fn (C:\Users\addin\flashcards-react\api\node_modules\@xata.io\client\src\schema\repository.ts:939:20)

